# How does one use Apple Photos to index photos on an external drive (if possible)?

Tags: hard-drive, photos, indexing, macos

I have never used **Photos** before except some bad experiences with it 10 years ago.
I would like to use **Photos** to index over 2Tb of photos on an external hard drive (*WD MyPassport*).

I have a 200Gb **iCloud** subscription that I do not wish to use for this, and a **MacBook Pro 2019** with a 500Gb hard drive where I don't want and cannot import the photos.

Part of what I want to accomplish includes looking up locations on a map to see what photos were taken where, searching photos of the same person, searching for text inside photos, etc.

The 2Tb Photos folder on the external is split up into around 40 folders, roughly one for each year I’ve been alive, so I can break down the process but it's not exactly a user friendly workflow.

### I have tried:

**File > Import > Selecting the whole "Photos" folder from the HD**

This crashes the **Photos** app because I assume the 2Tb folder is too large, [and I have to force quit it](https://imgur.com/8j5B57Z) (possibly damaging the `.photoslibrary` file in the process).

**File > Import > One smaller folder at a time**

This lists photos found in the folder [in a window that looks like this](https://imgur.com/5J0qg3q) (it takes about [ten minutes](https://imgur.com/1YVTyeW) to complete listing all the photos in the folder), then I click “**Import All New Items**” and it takes me to a blank, dead-end window [that looks like this](https://imgur.com/ZaUJpl9).

**Dragging a folder into the Photos window**

Usually results in [an error message](https://imgur.com/K7SYz1i) because some files it finds are not photos…

**Deleting the `.photoslibrary` files**

After a few failed attempts, I deleted the file but the app still doesn't seem to work as it's supposed to.

**I have been trying to do this for two months now and “it just doesn’t work”.**

### How can I use Apple Photos to index/catalog an external hard drive's photos?